# Why do I get "type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type" when creating a blanket implementation?

Tags: rust, traits

I'm trying to create a blanket implementation for all things that implement my `Cookie` trait, I want to implement ordering on `self.value()`,

```rust
pub trait Cookie: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn name(&self) -> String;   
    fn value(&self) -> String;  
}

use std::cmp;
impl<T: Cookie> cmp::Ord for T
{
    fn cmp(&self, other: &T ) -> cmp::Ordering {
        self.name().cmp( &other.name() )
    }
}
```

That's what I want, however when I try this, I get,

```
error[E0210]: type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type (e.g., `MyStruct<T>`)
  --> src/lib.rs:67:6
   |
67 | impl<T: Cookie> cmp::Ord for T
   |      ^ type parameter `T` must be used as the type parameter for some local type
   |
   = note: implementing a foreign trait is only possible if at least one of the types for which it is implemented is local
   = note: only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0210`.
error: could not compile `browser_cookie` (lib) due to previous error
```

But I'm not sure why that applies since my trait, Cookie, is obviously not foreign.

Comment: The error message itself is addressing a facet but not the core problem, the `note:`s below are more helpful for the code you are trying to write. i.e. What you're trying to do is not possible.

Comment: I don't get that @kmdreko. I read the notes. I'm not implementing a foreign trait. The trait I am implementing is local to the crate.  Core does this, look here where they implement the `Any` trait for all things `?Sized` how come that works? https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/any.rs.html#135

Comment: To be precise, you are *implementing* `Ord` on types with the *constraint* that they implement `Cookie`. And since `std::cmp::Ord` is not part of your crate, it is "foreign" and thus you cannot create a blanket implementation for it. The standard library can do that with `Any` because `Any` is a local trait within it.

Comment: I think this might be the best StackOverflow resource that addresses this case: [Can't implement a trait I don't own for all types that implement a trait I do own](/q/43989065/2189130)

Comment: @kmdreko that's the exact problem. and that's a really badly worded compiler error.