# How can I work around not being able to define Ord for all things that implement my trait nor being able to use trait objects with Ord?

Tags: rust

I previously [tried to implement `Ord` for all things that implement my trait: **you can see  my `Cookie` trait and my `Ord` implementation**.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77251932/124486) This wasn't possible though. My intent was to require a method called `value` which returned key as a string. And for `Ord` to use that in sorting. Now I'm trying to work around this. The part that requires `Ord`, I tried to add that to my CookieJar. I want to able to call `itertools.sorted()` which requires this.

```
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct CookieJar {
    _inner: std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<(dyn CookieElement + Ord)>> 
}
```

This also didn't work because Ord can't be turned into a trait object.

```
error[E0225]: only auto traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/cookiejar.rs:7:61
  |
7 |     _inner: std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<dyn Cookie + std::cmp::Ord>> 
  |                                                       ------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ additional non-auto trait
  |                                                       |
  |                                                       first non-auto trait
  |
  = help: consider creating a new trait with all of these as supertraits and using that trait here instead: `trait NewTrait: browser_cookie::Cookie + std::cmp::Ord {}`
  = note: auto-traits like `Send` and `Sync` are traits that have special properties; for more information on them, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#auto-traits>

error[E0038]: the trait `std::cmp::Ord` cannot be made into an object
   --> src/cookiejar.rs:7:48
    |
7   |     _inner: std::collections::HashMap<String, Box<dyn Cookie + std::cmp::Ord>> 
    |                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `std::cmp::Ord` cannot be made into an object
    |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
   --> /home/ecarroll/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/cmp.rs:293:15
    |
293 | pub trait Eq: PartialEq<Self> {
    |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because it uses `Self` as a type parameter
...
776 | pub trait Ord: Eq + PartialOrd<Self> {
    |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait cannot be made into an object because it uses `Self` as a type parameter

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0038, E0225.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0038`.
```

I don't understand this. [The description here is not easy to grok.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety)

How should I go about doing what I want here.

I want to be able to call `CookieJar.values().sorted()`

Comment: How would you like them sorted? Does the trait have a property (or properties) that can be used for the sorting criteria?

Comment: @kmdreko the sort criteria is whatever I set with Ord.

Comment: Naturally, but I was asking for something more concrete to ensure expectations are met. Right now what you've tried to express would mean the `Cookie` implementations would be `Ord` but that would only provide ordering within the same type and not other `Cookie` implementers. So any ordering on `dyn Cookie` would have to be done from the trait interface only thus I was asking what the criteria might look like to avoid assumptions. And it's easier to give good answers when all the pieces are known.

Comment: `CookieElement + Ord` is a generic bound! You can set a bound when generic types are being defined. Clearly, in your code, `Box<(dyn CookieElement + Ord)>` is not a generic definition, it is a usage of the generic defined in HashMap. BTW, IMO, implementation of Ord or PartialOrd for your base struct will solve the issue. For traits, you can extend those traits as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you own the trait, and it has a function that gets you a to sort by key, you can `impl Ord for dyn Cookie`:

```rust
use std::cmp::Ordering;
trait Cookie {
    fn name(&self) -> String;
}

impl PartialEq for dyn Cookie {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.name().eq(&other.name())
    }
}

impl Eq for dyn Cookie {}

impl PartialOrd for dyn Cookie {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        self.name().partial_cmp(&other.name())
    }
}

impl Ord for dyn Cookie {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
        self.name().cmp(&other.name())
    }
}
```

which will let you sort collections of `Box<dyn Cookie>` and other trait objects that deref to `dyn Cookie` as well as use [`Itertools::sorted`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.sorted.html) on collections of them.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=977a647205451b6bd57ed3faf66ab93f)

Comment: What a stupid compiler message and brain fart. So I had `impl<T: Cookie> cmp::Ord for T` and what I wanted was `impl Ord for dyn Cookie {}`. That's the nail on the head. I wish I understood why I wanted one or the other. And why only one of them is a violation of the coherence rules. But this is 100% what I wanted. I liked the first answer with `Box<>` too, but it was a bit wtf. This is perfect. You++.

Comment: Actually, I'll ask this in a follow up.

Comment: I think there is an answer somewhere on here already. Essentialy `T: Cookie` is any type that implements `Cookie` even foreign ones, `dyn Cookie` is a single of these types. Replacing the former with the latter doesn't always work, it works here because `self` is never taken by value, only behind references.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77252556/124486

Answer (score 0):

Does `CookieJar` need to use dynamic dispatch (`Box<dyn Cookie>`)?
Personally, I would just parameterise it:

```rust
#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct CookieJar<C: Cookie> {
    _inner: std::collections::HashMap<String, C> 
}
```

The only reason you would need a `CookieJar` with `Box<dyn Cookie>` is if you are storing different types that implement `Cookie` inside it.

Please note I have made some assumptions about the Cookie trait in the completed example below.

```rust
pub trait Cookie: std::fmt::Debug {}

impl Cookie for i32 {}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
pub struct CookieJar<C: Cookie> {
    _inner: std::collections::HashMap<String, C>,
}

pub fn main() {
    let jar = CookieJar {
        _inner: [
            ("cookie1".into(), 5),
            ("cookie2".into(), 12),
            ("cookie3".into(), -2),
            ("cookie4".into(), 2),
        ].into_iter().collect()
    };
    let mut values: Vec<&i32> = jar._inner.values().collect();
    values.sort();
    println!("{:?}", values)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac47487152d2a46fddaf9a281a4e61b5)

This prints `[-2, 2, 5, 12]`.

The reason this works is because Ord is implemented for &i32, and so Rust is able to sort a `Vec<&i32>`. If you want to add this as a generic function to return the sorted values, it would look like this:

```rust
impl<C: Cookie + Ord> CookieJar<C> {
    fn sorted_values(&self) -> Vec<&C> {
        let mut values: Vec<&C> = self._inner.values().collect();
        values.sort();
        values
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2e9f0ca0359e93113a8cec980901ac8c)

Please note that `.sorted()` is not present in std Rust (see [here](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/add-a-vec-sorted-function/11948/6)), and unless `Deref<HashMap<String, C>` is implemented for `CookieJar<C>`, or you manually implement it for yourself, you cannot call `CookieJar.values()`.

Correction (thanks [cafce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/442760/cafce25)):
`.sorted()` is not available in Rust's standard library but it is available in the `itertools` crate, which is probably what you were talking about. My main point around generics still stands (as well as `.values()`) but feel free to call `.sorted()` to your hearts content.

Comment: `sorted()` might not be in `std` but it's definitely [available in `itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/fn.sorted.html) which is the function OP is talking about.

Comment: Whoops, forgot about that! Thanks for the correction.