# How can I reason about these two different syntaxs involving trait objects and blanket implementations?

Tags: rust

I had written a Blanket Ord implementation like this,

```
impl<T: Cookie> cmp::Ord for T {}
```

Turns out, I wanted this,

```
impl Ord for dyn Cookie { }
```

I'm not sure why though. For me I read the top as "for anything that implements Cookie, implement Ord." And I kind of read the bottom one the same way. [The error message didn't help me out at all.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77251932/124486) How should I think about these two constructs?

Comment: When I say `dyn T`. I'm saying T implemented without monomorphism, that allows type polymorphism using dynamic dispatch. I get all that. What I don't get is why _any_ of that matters to the coherence rules. That's an implementations detail. How come I can define a trait I don't own using a trait I do own with dyn. But I can't define a trait I don't own using a trait I do own without it. Why is it special. Why does it have more lax'd coherence rules.

Comment: Because `dyn Trait` is a type. And if `Trait` is local, so is the type `dyn Trait`. But `Trait` is not a type. It's a trait. And `T: Trait` is not a type either. It's a trait bound. And `T` in `impl<T>` is a type parameter. Kind of a type, but it is not local. So you cannot implement foreign trait for it, as it is a foreign type.

Answer (score 0):

`dyn Trait` isn't "anything that implements `Trait`", instead it is it's very own type, a trait object of `Trait`, different from every other type that implements `Trait`. What has got you confused is likely the fact that you can *convert* pointers to types that implement `Trait` to pointers that point to `dyn Trait`.

Since `dyn Trait` for your `Trait` is local to your crate you can implement arbitrary traits for a variable of it's type. No other crate (except the owner of the other trait) can implement any trait for `dyn Trait` either. So it's safe for you to implement traits for it, as opposed to `T: Trait` which can be a foreign type and another crate can have implemented the trait you want to implement for it.

And you can't just use any type that implements `Trait` as a `dyn Trait` either, you have to convert from that type to a `dyn Trait` first, though that *can* happen automatically through coercion

As an example, both commented lines result in an error because while `i8: Any` holds, `i8` is not a `dyn Any` they are fundamentally different types.

```
use std::any::Any;
fn main() {
    let a: Box<i8> = Box::new(0);
    let i8_reference = &a;
    takes_i8_box_reference(i8_reference);
    // takes_dyn_any_box_reference(i8_reference); // Error
    let a_any: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(0);
    let any_reference: &Box<dyn Any> = &a_any;
    // takes_i8_box_reference(any_reference); // Error
    takes_dyn_any_box_reference(any_reference);
}
fn takes_i8_box_reference(_: &Box<i8>) {}
fn takes_dyn_any_box_reference(_: &Box<dyn Any>) {}
```